# Flask SQLAlchemy Contains/Ilike producing different results?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to query a column from a database with contains/ilike, they are producing different results. Any idea why?

My current code;

```
search = 'nel'

find = Clients.query.filter(Clients.lastName.ilike(search)).all()
# THE ABOVE LINE PRODUCES 0 RESULTS

find = Clients.query.filter(Clients.lastName.contains(search)).all()
# THE ABOVE LINE PRODUCES THE DESIRED RESULTS

for row in find:
    print(row.lastName)
```

My concern is am I missing something? I have read that 'contains' does not always work either. Is there a better way to do what I am doing?

Answer (score 7):

For `ilike` and `like`, you need to include wildcards in your search like this:

```
Clients.lastName.ilike(r"%{}%".format(search))
```

As the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html) say:

> LIKE pattern matching always covers the entire string. Therefore, to match a sequence anywhere within a string, the pattern must start and end with a percent sign.

The other difference is that `contains` is case-sensitive, while `ilike` is insensitive.